# Custom average function with array input does not return value in C

Tags: c, function, average

I made a program which accepts input for 30 users (About their age)
and then the array was supposed to be an input in a custom function made by me (avg_age)
However the average printed on screen is 0.0000 (for 30 non-zero values)
That is why I think it does not return anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float avg_age(int age[]);

main()

{
    int i=0,age[30]={0},intemp;

do{
    printf("Input age for 30 users: ");
    scanf("%d",&intemp);
    if(intemp>0 && intemp<100)
        intemp=age[i];
    else i--;
    i++;
}while(i<30 || intemp<0 || intemp>100);

printf("\nAverage age of 30 users: %f\n",avg_age(age));




float avg_age(int age[]){
    int i,avg=0;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        avg+=age[i];
    avg=(float)avg/30;
    return avg;
    }

}
```

Comment: `intemp=age[i];`=> `age[i]=intemp;`. You're not storing the ages in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the function definition of `avg_age` out of the `main`. You declared `avg` as `int` but it should be declared `float` to store `float` values.

```
float avg = 0.0;
```

In `main` `intemp=age[i];` is not storing the inputs to the array `age` instead assigning `0` each time to `intemp`. Change it to

```
age[i] = intemp;
```

Your modified code: (for 5 users)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

float avg_age(int age[]);

int main(void)
{
    int i=0,age[N]={0},intemp;

    do{
       printf("Input age for %d users: ", N);
       scanf("%d",&intemp);
       if(intemp>0 && intemp<100)
           age[i] = intemp;
       else i--;
       i++;
    }while(i<N || intemp<0 || intemp>100);

    printf("\nAverage age of %d users: %f\n",N, avg_age(age));
    return 0;
}

float avg_age(int age[]){
    int i;
    float avg=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        avg+=age[i];
    avg=(float)avg/N;
    return avg;
 }
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/bQ5RoZ) is the tested code.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I will say that you might explain the reasoning behind what you said instead of just saying "do it this way".

Comment: @ChronoKitsune; I do not think that was the issue although I fixed that.

Comment: Quibble: the number of entries in the array should be passed as an argument to `avg_age`, rather than having the function rely on the presence of a global symbol like `N`.  Loose coupling is a good habit to get into as early as possible.

Comment: @JohnBode; Passing array size is a good practice. But I do not think `N` is causing any problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `avg` inside `avg_age` should be a `float`

```
float avg_age(int age[]){
  int i; float sum=0.0;
  for(i=0;i<30;i++)
     sum += age[i];
  return sum/30;
}
```

and of course the above function should be outside of `main` (preferably before it).

BTW, you should have compiled with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`). The compiler certainly would have warned you! Also, learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Both of them are outdated. Turbo C is obsolete now. Developers stopped giving support to Dev-C++ 4.9.9.4.

Comment: @niCk: Consider switching to Linux... It is free, and you will learn a lot! So install it on your computer!

Comment: Which scripts? You have only a C source file! Your instructor cannot see if you are using Linux, Windows or MacOSX (or Hurd or BeOS) on your own computer ...

Comment: If forced to use Windows, look at MinGW as a nice platform to have a bash shell, the gcc toolchain and other tools you're familiar with from Ubuntu.  Simpler than full-blown Cygwin.